# How to remove google.visualization.Dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to use this example of charts in the dashboard:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartrangefilter_control

To initiate and draw I call "drawVisualization()" function, but I need to be able to remove the charts like it was before calling "drawVisualization()", how could I do that? I didn't find any information how to dispose. I tried dashboard.dispose(); but that doesn't work as I need. So how to remove dashboard with its controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make these variables global:

```
chart;
control;
dashboard;
```

And use:

```
function disposeShit()
{
    chart.visualization.clearChart();
    control.visualization.dispose();
   dashboard.dispose();
}
```